# Combine CSV files with condition

Tags: bash, shell

I need to combine all the csv files in some directory (.csv), provided that there are other files with the same name in this directory, but with different expansion (.csv.done).

If a csv file doesn't have `.done` in this extension then I don't need it for combine process.

What is the best way to do it using Bash ?

Answer (score 1):

This approach is a solution to your problem. I see you've commented that it "didn't work", but whatever the reason is for it not working, it's likely simple to fix e.g. if you forgot to include key details, or failed to adapt it appropriately to suit your specific situation. If you need further help troubleshooting, add more info to your question.

The approach:

```
for f in *.csv.done
do
  cat "${f%.*}" >> combined_file.csv
done
```

How it works:

- In your example, you have 3 files named 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv and two 'done' files named 1.csv.done 2.csv.done.
- This script begins by making a list of all files that end in .csv.done (two files: 1.csv.done 2.csv.done).
- It then uses a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), specifically `${parameter%word}`, to 'shorten' the name of the two files in the list to .csv (instead of .csv.done).
- Then it 'prints' the content of the two 'shortened' filenames (1.csv and 2.csv) into a 'combined' file.
- It doesn't 'print' the content of 1.csv.done or 2.csv.done, or 3.csv, because these files weren't in the original 'list'.
- If you run this script multiple times, it will keep adding the contents of files 1.csv and 2.csv to the 'combined' file (only run it once, or delete the 'combined' file before running it again)

Comment: I tried , but this script cat all my csv files in directory even without ".done" file ...

Comment: For example, I have 5 files in one directory:  
1.csv ,   2.csv,   3.csv,  1.csv.done,   2.csv.done

I need to cat "1.csv" and "2.csv"  (without "3.csv"). 

Im think I need modify the  "${f%.*}" in your script, but I dont know how... im only start learning bash.

Comment: `cat ${f%.*} | cut -d"." -f-2 >> combined_file.csv`

I can rewrite like this and its work correct, but if I'll receive file with another one "." in filename it will be a problem. I need just substring filename without last 5 letters but I can't understand how can I use "cut" command to do it